# How do I export members of a nested Python enum into the containing class?

Tags: python, enums, class-variables

I have a Python class that contains a `state` field. To define all possible states, I have declared a nested enumeration:

```py
class Foo:
    class State(enum.Enum):
        Unloaded = enum.auto()
        Loaded = enum.auto()
        Processed = enum.auto()

    state: State
```

However, it is a bit cumbersome to write code like this:

```py
if foo.state == Foo.State.Unloaded:
    do_something_with(foo)
    foo.state = Foo.State.Loaded
```

---

I want to make the enumeration members accessible directly as members of `Foo` (like `Foo.Unloaded`, `Foo.Loaded` and `Foo.Processed`). Is there a better way than just assigning them by hand?

```py
class Foo:
    class State(enum.Enum):
        Unloaded = enum.auto()
        Loaded = enum.auto()
        Processed = enum.auto()

    Unloaded = State.Unloaded
    Loaded = State.Loaded
    Processed = State.Processed

    state: State
```

Comment: The general answer is _"don't use nested classes"_. For the most, they just create edge cases and problems. You'd likely be better off with just declaring a `FooState` enum at the module level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can always dynamically do something like this. But why nest the enum at all then?

```
import enum

class State(enum.Enum):
    Unloaded = enum.auto()
    Loaded = enum.auto()
    Processed = enum.auto()

class Foo:
    state: State


for member in State:
    setattr(Foo, member.name, member)
```

Or, without the loop:

```
vars(Foo).update(State.__members__)
```

Note, in general, nesting class definitions is not a common construct in Python. Even if I wanted something like your original approach (I happen to think requiring `Foo.State.whatever` is not cumbersome but *good* **if** you are going to have nesting), then you would just do:

```
import enum

class State(enum.Enum):
    Unloaded = enum.auto()
    Loaded = enum.auto()
    Processed = enum.auto()

class Foo:
    State = State
    state: State
```

Which is probably what I would use if I wanted that. But frankly, I would probably just leave state at the same level as `Foo`. So what I would probably just use is:

```
import enum


class State(enum.Enum):
    Unloaded = enum.auto()
    Loaded = enum.auto()
    Processed = enum.auto()

class Foo:
    state: State
```

Comment: _"But why nest the enum at all then?"_ I considered the alternative, but it seemed more ergonomic to me to write `Foo.Unloaded` than `FooState.Unloaded` (or `Foo.State.Unloaded`). Anyway, thanks for the comprehensive answer!